# How can I get a part of a key in HashMap?

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

![a txt file example] [1] http://dox.bg/files/dw?a=f49baaafee

! [what are the numbers actually] [2] http://dox.bg/files/dw?a=a911da0422

I got a text fle iot.txt and I red in it and store its data in a `Map<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>`.
As you see in the text file we have an exact period "2004-11-28 - 2004-12-04" then languages (Java, Python, etc.) and at the end, an integer(interest in this language), which is the value of these languages.
**How loop through the years only, not mentioning specific week**. E.g
Iterate through **2004** and get the least interest. Iterate through **2006**. Also, I have years 2004-2015 so is there any fast way to loop for each of all years?
I was wondering doing something like that:

```
Map<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> everything = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, Integer> lang = new HashMap<>();
    for(String yr: iot.keySet())
    {   
    lang.put(yr, iot.get(yr).get("JavaScript").intValue());
    everything.put(yr, lang);

    for(String yr04 : iot.get("2004").keySet())  //this is where I have prob
    {
    int minValueInMap=(Collections.min(everything.values()));  // there is smth wrong with "min" 
    if (entry.getValue()==minValueInMap)  //entry cannot be resolved??
    {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());  //entry cannot be resolved??
    }
    }
```

However, it cannot be done as my keys are sorted like "2004-11-28 - 2004-12-04" .

Comment: You'll have to loop through the entire `keySet()` and then do a string comparison on each key to see if it matches.  Alternatively, you'll have to store the data in a map more suitable to your query.

Comment: I think you should think of adding your code and Sample data in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using a better data structure to represent what you need. However, failing that you could extend HashMap like the below:

```
public class MyHashMap<V> extends HashMap<String,V> {

    public Set<String> keysStartingWith(String s) {
        Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
        for(String key : keySet()) {
            if(key.startsWith(s)) {
                result.add(key);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Instead of using a Map> you would use:

```
MyHashMap<HashMap<String, Integer>> myHashMap = new MyHashMap<>();
HashMap<String, Integer> data;
for(String yearRangeKey : myHashMap.keysStartingWith("2014") {
   data = myHashMap.get(yearRangeKey);
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### What you are looking for is called a `Multimap`:

> A collection that maps keys to values, similar to Map, but in which
>   each key may be associated with multiple values. You can visualize the
>   contents of a multimap either as a map from keys to nonempty
>   collections of values: `a → 1, 2` and `b → 3`

You have to store your data in two maps if you want it searchable by both the native key and just the year.

Then when you put something in the map with the full date, you also put it in the `Multimap` with just the year.

[Guava has something called a `Multimap` that is perfect for this.](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

#### You do not want to loop through the `keySet()` doing comparisons.

This will get expensive very quickly. If you build the `Multimap` as you build the other map then you have very quick look ups to find everything in a given year very quickly with one simple method call to `.get()` with the year and you will get back a `List` or `Set` of the matching data depending on which implementation of the `Multimap` you chose.

Comment: I read everything about Multi Map. In the link you sent me, could you please give me an example how to make a Multi Map and replace the initial key "2004-11-28 - 2004-12-04"  and its values with the key "2004" . Thanks

Comment: are you not familar with `.substring()`?

Comment: Yeah, I am but I don't see how it would work.

Comment: then you need to go back and do some remedial studying of how to put things into maps with a key, this has become too broad a question for a specific answer at this point

Comment: you first need to look carefully at my question, look at my code and probably see that I already know how to put values into a particular key. I looked for a solution which will not take more than 10 lines of code. The whole data in the document is ridiculously big to put it all again over a new map. That is why I simply asked how I can ACCESS the key just by the " .substring[0] " or whatever you call it (just the YEAR) . The method .startswith did not work for me also.

Comment: I looked at the code and the question, I gave you a solution as did others ( of various quality ) you do not understand them, that is the problem not that we did not read your question or look at your code. We need the *"minimal understanding/you won't comprehend the answer"* close reason back at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Use streams:

```
Map<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> everything = new HashMap<>();
String year = "2004";
int minInterest2004 = everything.entrySet().stream()
  .filter(e -> e.getKey().startsWith(year))
  .mapToInt(e -> e.getValue().getInterest())
  .min().getAsInt();
```

Comment: Sorry. I am now reading API for stream. But cannot get what you are doing. However it would be good if you explain me why the code does not work : 
.mapToInt(e -> e.getValue().getInterest())  // The method          getInterest() is undefined for the type HashMap<String, Integer>

Comment: this is way over their head if they do not understand how to apply `.startsWith()` or `.substring()` to pull just the year off and use it as a key